# Xcode 4.3.2 crash on build

Tags: xcode, build, crash, osx-lion, quit

I'm running Lion (10.7.4) and running Xcode 4.3.2 and when I build any application it crashes on the build. Below is the report. Any suggestions?

```
   Application Specific Information:
   ProductBuildVersion: 4E2002
   UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Couldn't load plug-in 'com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB' while firing fault for extension 'Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.LLDB'
    UserInfo: {
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 \"Loading a plug-in failed.\" UserInfo=0x402919560 {DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in \U201ccom.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB\U201d at path \U201c/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin\U201d could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x4014c5d00 \"The bundle \U201cDebuggerLLDB\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.\"}";
}
Hints: None
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem. The LLVM compiler has a bug, supposedly Apple knows about it according to a recent forum. So, build your app through GDB by going to "Edit Project Scheme" and choosing GDB instead of LLVM for the build sequence.

Comment: Same problem here with xcode 4.6.3 and mac osx 10.7.5, tried everything but your solution works perfectly!  Thank you.